# Complexity analysis of QuickSort from first principles

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am trying to learn about complexity analysis and how to perform it from first principles. Take QuickSort as an example, I would like to be able to derive an O-notation expression for the average-case complexity of this algorithm.

I know QuickSort is O(nlog(n)) and I understand why, it has to make a pass over n elements on each iteration, and the recursion depth is log n. But I dont know how you would show this with first principles, ie counting primitive operations.

Comment: This is precisely covered at e.g. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis.  See also [*Introduction to Algorithms*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Algorithms-T-Cormen/dp/0262533057/).

Comment: +1 For Cormen reference.

Comment: But in relation to deriving the complexity from 'first principles'. Doesn't first principles mean counting primitive operations?

Comment: @Jim_CS: You don't need to count individual primitive operations.  It doesn't matter whether there are 10 or 100 ops per iteration/recursion, so long as that number is constant.  The growth is controlled by the number of iterations/recursions.

Comment: Rather than closing this question, I think it's worth putting the Wikipedia reference in an answer and voting it up.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Link-only answers are usually frowned-upon; there's no guarantee that the Wikipedia content will be the same in the future, at which point the answer becomes useless.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I didn't intend to suggest that it should be a link only.  Just that this is a good question, and people will look here for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knuth, in *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3 (Sorting and Searching)*, section 5.2.2 (Sorting by Exchanges), presents a detailed analysis of a concrete implementation of quicksort (in MIX, of course). He's probably the only person in the world who would care enough to do an analysis of this kind by hand, for human consumption.